# Parsing in bash - extract content from brackets

Tags: bash

The input to my bash script can be of the form [fec1::1]:80 or []:80. The second input implies that there's no IP address given. My bash script is to split the input into IP and port. With the said second input, the script should 'understand' that no IP was given.

The following logic seems to solve my problem, on the bash prompt:

```
$ ip=[]:78
$  echo $ip
[]:78
$ temp=(`echo $ip | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'`)
$ echo $temp

$
```

When I try to do the same thing from within a script, the result is different:

```
local_endpoint="$1"
printf 'local_endpoint: %s\n' "$local_endpoint"
IN="$local_endpoint"

local_ip=$(echo "$IN" | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}')
if [ -z "$local_ip" ] ; then
   local_ip=$(echo "$IN" | awk -F':' '{print $1}')
   local_port=$(echo "$IN" | awk -F':' '{print $2}')
else
   local_port=$(echo "$IN" | awk -F'[][]' '{print $3}' | awk -F':' '{print $2}')
fi

printf 'IP: %s\n' $local_ip
printf 'port: %d\n' $local_port

if [ -z "$local_port" -a -z "$local_ip" ] ; then
   printf 'No port and IP was given\n'
elif [ -z "$local_ip" ] ; then
   printf 'No IP was given\n'
elif [ -z "$local_port" ] ; then
   printf 'No port was given\n'
fi
exit 2
```

Output:

```
# ./temp.sh []:829
local_endpoint: []:829
IP: []
port: 829
```

Any idea on what's happening? Also, why do I see the extra comma (,) at the end of the output?

Comment: `printf 'port: %d\n', $local_port` will print comma at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is missing quoting at many places and there are stray commas too in `printf`. This script should work:

```
local_endpoint="$1"
printf 'local_endpoint: %s\n' "$local_endpoint"
IN="$local_endpoint"

if [[  "$IN" == "["* ]] ; then
   local_ip=$(echo "$IN" | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}')
   local_port=$(echo "$IN" | awk -F'[][]' '{print $3}' | awk -F':' '{print $2}')
else
   local_ip=$(echo "$IN" | awk -F':' '{print $1}')
   local_port=$(echo "$IN" | awk -F':' '{print $2}')
fi

printf 'IP: <%s>\n' "$local_ip"
printf 'port: <%d>\n' "$local_port"

if [ -z "$local_port" -a -z "$local_ip" ] ; then
   printf 'No port and IP was given\n'
elif [ -z "$local_ip" ] ; then
   printf 'No IP was given\n'
elif [ -z "$local_port" ] ; then
   printf 'No port was given\n'
fi
exit 2
```

Comment: I've updated my question with a slight modification of your changes to the script. It still does not produce the desired result. Any thoughts on what is missing?

Comment: If you supply empty IP it will print empty output. Run your script as:  `./temp.sh "[fec1::1]:80"`

Comment: I tried running it with and without the quotes around the argument []:80, but the result is the same; output shows IP: []. I want the script to know and display the IP as null.

Comment: Not getting it, did you run `./temp.sh "[fec1::1]:80"` and check the output or not? When you run `./temp.sh "[]:80"` you are passing empty IP then it rightly prints: **`No IP was given`** in output.

Comment: Please refer the updated script and its output in my question. When the IP address is given, the output is correct. But when it is not given - "[]:80" - the output is not right.

Comment: That means you didn't copy/paste my script correctly. I am running script as per my answer. Can you tell me what changes you made in this?

Comment: I did use your script, and made changes on top of it, keeping in mind the suggestions provided. One change is to replace (`...`) with $(...). The others are mostly additional logic I put in to complete the script's purpose.

Comment: ok this new line is the problem `local_ip=$(echo "$IN" | awk -F':' '{print $1}')`  If IP is empty then you are setting literal `[]` to `local_ip` which is WRONG.

Comment: OK, got it. I need to be able to distinguish between the two inputs from my script: [fec1:11]:80 and 10.20.30.40:80. If the input is of type former, IP would be fec1::11 and port 80. If it's of the latter type, IP would be 10.20.30.40 and port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Process substitution is:

```
var=$(command ...)
```

not

```
var=(command ...)
```